# UIImage from NSData works fine on iPad2 but not on iPad1

Tags: ios, ipad, asynchronous, uiimage, nsdata

I just ran into a very strange issue.
I currently developing an application that loads images from a remote host in an asynchronous matter and then displays them.

the following code is being performed in a background thread, invoked via `performSelectorInBackground`

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ChannelThumbnailURI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{PersonName}" withString:person.Name]];  
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

funny thing now is that I get different results on different devices (all with the same iOS, 4.3.3)

thumb is nil on my old iPad while in the same context its a valid image on my iPad2

I really have no clue what the issue could be here.
thanks for your input.

sam

Comment: Try to debug by checking url value / NSData length to identify where issue is coming from, I bet this is a human error (like a bad url because of a missing `person.Name`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see an immediate reason why this would work on an iPad2 and not on an iPad1, try adding some more debug code to see where it goes wrong.

```
NSString* urlString = [ChannelThumbnailURI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{PersonName}" withString:person.Name];
if (urlString == nil) { ... }
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
if (url == nil) { ... } 
NSError* error = nil; 
NSData *imageData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    [error release];
}
UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```